# delphi XE10, is it possible to execute a thread in thread

Tags: delphi, thread-safety

Is it safe to start an (independent) thread from the Execute code of another thread in Delphi application?

Comment: *is it possible*? is very seldom well received here, as it's too broad. Almost anything is *possible*, and an answer that says *Most likely* isn't going to help you much.  *is it safe*? Safe in regards to what? Will it jeopardize world peace or the climate? No. Can it cause problems in some cases? Yes. Will it cause your eyes to bleed? Probably not. You're going to need to be much more specific about what you're asking.

Comment: Threads cannot be nested. So you cannot executena thread in a different thread. That's a non sequiteur. Can you start one thread from another? Of course you can. Every time you create a thread you create it from another thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it safe to start an (independent) thread from the Execute code of another thread in Delphi application?

Of course it is.  Why would you think it is not?  Any thread can *start* another independent thread.  Where do you think your original worker thread gets started from?  It is started from the main thread.

You have to be careful of thread safety if the newly started thread shares data/resources with other threads.  But if it is completely independent and self-contained then it is complete thread-safe.